# MODBUS Word conversion

Tags: c#, modbus, rs485

I am getting data from a Carlo Gavazzi meter. The MODBUS data is 2 words in length, it is a signed 32 bit integer. How do I convert this into a real number in C#. I get an integer back, for example, 16002, I want to be able to convert this into the value that is displayed on the front of the device.

In summary:
Convert two-word 32 bit signed integer into its real value.

Comment: Use [BitConverter.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_Byte___System_Int32_) to convert your byte array to an int. Note that you'll have to check the endianness of your data and adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the meter is in another country. All I know is that the value is just MODBUS data, so won't be its actual value.

Comment: So I am not too sure how to check the endianness as all I get is an integer value. And thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: A signed 32 bit integer is a number, are you asking how to convert it to a floating point (real) number? Modbus numbers are often scaled (times 10) or encoded as a 32 bit number, you'll have to read the manual to find out if it is a simple scaling, or if you need to do a bitwise conversion to a floating point number. Can you link the manual for the particular meter you are using?

Comment: Fortunately, there is a good manual available. It gives me the conversion factors as well. In part 2.1 I will need to dust off my college books! https://www.shmmetershop.co.uk/shop/files/attachments/280/EM210%20Modbus%20Table.pdf

Comment: Just so the information is all out there, the register I want to test this on is 30053 and is a 32 bit signed int with a scale of 10. The last value I had from it was 16002.

Comment: So you have the manual in your hands and you are asking others "how do I do this?".  Modbus dates from the early 80s when bytes cost real money.  Their data formats are designed to be memory efficient.  So, a measurement is represented by two bytes.  You need to understand what those two bytes mean.  C# gives you full access to the bits in a number, so you can do anything you want, once you decide what you want to do.  If your code doesn't work, post the description of what you are trying to do and your code and we can help.  But, don't expect anyone to remember Modbus stuff by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting 2 16-bit unsigned registers into a 32-bit signed value can be done as shown below. This can be done in one statement, but I will do it in steps for clarity.  Assuming that you have the upper and lower words (16-bit) in upper16 and lower 16 respectively:

```
UInt32 uint32 = upper16;
uint32 <<= 16;
uint32 |= lower16;
Int32 sint32 = (Int32)uint32;
```

Based on this statement in the documentation:

```
For all the formats the byte order (inside the single word) is MSB->LSB. 
In INT32, UINT32 and UINT64 formats, the word order is LSW-> MSW."
```

It looks like

```
lower16 = address 30053
upper16 = address 30054
```

You mentioned in a comment that it has a scale of 10.  Usually that is done so that you can give some precision to the value (floating point value).  So you would probably do:

```
double value = sint32 / 10.0;
```

OR

```
double kW = sint32 / 10.0; // In your case
```

Comment: Thank you @Marker. I will post my code on here...I am hoping to get real values from device display tomorrow. I will then write some code and post it on here.